# Checking epsilon-delta proofs: finding "nice" deltas

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I have the following limit epsilon-delta proof of a limit along with my proof response:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,3)}{\frac{x}{y}=\frac{1}{3}}$$

---

Pick $\epsilon >0$ and $\delta=\frac{9\epsilon}{4-3\epsilon}.$ Suppose $0<||(x,y)-(1,3)||<\delta$ for $y≠0$. Then

\begin{align*}
|f(x,y)-l|&=\left|\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{3}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{3x-y}{3y}\right|=\left|\frac{3x-y+3-3}{3y}\right|\\
&=\frac{|3(x-1)+(3-y)|}{|3y|} \\
&≤\frac{3|x-1|+|y-3|}{3|y|}
<\frac{3\delta+\delta}{3|y|}=\frac{4\delta}{3|y|}\\
&<\frac{4\delta}{3(\delta+3)}=\frac{4\delta}{3\delta+9}=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Note that the first inequality is because $|y-3|≤\sqrt{(x-1^2)+(y-3)^2}=||(x,y)-(1,3)||<\delta$.

So $\delta =\frac{9\varepsilon}{4-3\varepsilon}$.

---

I am quite new to formal limit proofs, so am not sure whether or not the layout of my proof is okay—the examples I've seen all progress with their argument in quite a "linear" fashion (i.e., finding some delta eventually at the end of the proof), whereas I've directly started with a "pick $\delta=...$.

My main concern is that my choice of delta is quite "ugly" since most of the examples in my textbook and lectures are all quite "nice" and simple, i.e. $\delta=2\epsilon.$

Comment: Everything seems alright except the line $\frac{4 \delta}{3|y|} \lt \frac{4 \delta}{3 \delta+3}$. Here you assume that $|y| \gt \delta +3$. However from $|y-3| \lt \delta$, we can only conclude that $|y| \lt \delta +3$.

Comment: Do you have a hint as to how to fix it? i.e., how would I then get the final < $\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no reason you have to get to "$=\varepsilon$" at the end.
It is just as good to have "$<\varepsilon$".

If you think your formula for finding $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$ is "ugly",
try a smaller $\delta$ that is "prettier".
You can always make $\delta$ smaller as long as it remains positive.

Second, there is an error in your proof.
It is true that $0 < \lvert y\rvert < \delta + 3$, but that fact implies that
$$
\frac{4\delta}{3|y|} > \frac{4\delta}{3(\delta+3)}.
$$
The inequality is in the wrong direction for what you need.

Also note that if when you say $\varepsilon > 0$, you often have to be careful about large values of $\varepsilon$.
Your formula, $\delta=\frac{9\varepsilon}{4-3\varepsilon}$,
produces a negative value of $\delta$ if $\varepsilon > \frac43$.
If you had a proof in which the formula $\delta=\frac{9\varepsilon}{4-3\varepsilon}$
worked for small values of $\varepsilon$,
you could fix the proof by making an even more complicated rule for finding $\delta$.
For example, you might use your formula only when $\varepsilon \leq 1$ and otherwise set $\delta$ to a specified fixed value.
For this particular formula, however, you could also simplify the formula by recognizing that if the formula is valid at all then $0 < 4 -3\varepsilon < 4$ and therefore
$$
\frac{9\varepsilon}{4} < \frac{9\varepsilon}{4-3\varepsilon}.
$$
So you could just set $\delta$ to $\frac94\varepsilon$ or something smaller.
(Note that this doesn't mean $\delta=\frac94\varepsilon$ is a good choice for
the limit in the question; it fails because $\lvert y\rvert$ can be less than $3$.
I'm merely explaining how you could simplify the expression if it were correct.)

Comment: But I thought that when considering a limit, we would only care about the very small values of $\epsilon>0$, i.e., some small region around the point of which we're taking the limit of. Does it really matter/make sense to consider what happens for large |epsilon| > 1?

Comment: The definition doesn't say "for all $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\varepsilon < 1$". It simply says "for all $\varepsilon >0$". If you don't have a proof that works for **all** positive $\varepsilon$ then you haven't proved the definition applies. Of course if a certain $\delta$ satisfies the definition for $\varepsilon = 1$ then it also satisfies the definition for all larger values of $\varepsilon$, and people sometimes use that fact to simplify a proof.

Comment: So $|y-3|:=\begin{cases}y-3, \text{ if y-3≥0} \\ -y+3, \text{ if y-3<0}\end{cases}$, so $y-3<\delta\implies y<\delta+3$ OR $-y+3<\delta\implies y>3-\delta.$ Thus $y\in (3-\delta, \delta+3)$. Then I can choose ANY $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ to complete my proof, i.e, pick $delta=\frac{1}{2}$ so that $y>\frac{5}{2}\implies \frac{1}{|y|}<\frac{2}{5}$? Hence, 

$$\frac{4\delta}{3|y|}<\frac{8\delta}{15}.$$ So take $\frac{8\delta}{15}=\varepsilon$ and be done with the proof. 

Furthermore, we can take ANY $\frac{4\delta}{3|y|}< \varepsilon <\frac{8\delta}{15}$.

Is my reasoning ok?

Comment: @JasonXu I think $\delta = \frac{1}{2} $ should be replaced by  $\delta = \min \{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{15 \varepsilon}{8} \}$ .